# How do I color points using ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am attempting to graph two variables and then use a gradient colour scheme for visual emphasis - however, it keeps giving me a black scatterplot as if I didn't type the command.

Fake Dataset:

```r
Nature_DR = data.frame(Protect_LGA = runif(100, min=0, max=87.5),
                       DR_2011_Protect = runif(100, min=3, max=10))
```

Here is my code

```r
    ggplot(Nature_DR, aes(x=Protect_LGA, y=DR_2011_Protect)) +
      geom_point() + 
      scale_fill_gradient(low="yellow", high ="green") + 
      geom_smooth(method = 'loess') +
      coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,87.5), ylim = c(3,10)) + 
      labs(x="Proportion of LGA that is protected", 
           y = "Standardised Death Rates in 2011",
           title = "Relation between Protected Areas and Death Rates")
```

Comment: Can you please post example of your data (`head(Nature_DR)`)?

Comment: you haven't mapped any variable to colour in the aes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have asked `ggplot` to apply a color gradient to the `fill` aesthetic, but you have not specified a `fill` aesthetic.  In addition, `geom_point()` does not use the `fill` aesthetic, it uses the `color` aesthetic.

So, for example, you could color the points by `DR_2011_Protect` using the following, which will use the default color gradient:

```
   ggplot(Nature_DR, aes(x=Protect_LGA, y=DR_2011_Protect, color=DR_2011_Protect)) +
     geom_point()
```

Or apply your color gradient to the points by changing which scale you modify:

```
   ggplot(Nature_DR, aes(x=Protect_LGA, y=DR_2011_Protect, color=DR_2011_Protect)) + 
     geom_point() + 
     scale_color_gradient(low="yellow", high ="green")
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I change where the gradient changes colour? i.e I want it to go to the high colour sooner

Comment: Look at documentation for `scale_color_gradientn()`, `scale_color_manual()`, `scale_color_gradient2()`